# Prevent autocomplete vim-go split screen

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

I made script to install my golang dev enviroment with vim, but my installation have annoying thing. ([Here](https://gist.github.com/lucasmenendez/f4598913f15c1d3fc1d5a5f97376326d) is my script)

When i use neocomplete and vim-go, autocompletion works fine but when i try to choose one of suggestions, the screen is splitted, and on top view print the same option that i am with cursor. Like this:
[image]

Comment: off-topic because it belongs on http://vi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is window is the preview window. This window can be set to show up during insert completion when `'completeopt'` has `preview` set. You can disable this by adding the following to your `vimrc` file:

```
set completeopt-=preview
```

You can also close the preview window manually via `<c-w>z`/`<c-w><c-z>` or `:pclose`

If you want to keep the preview window but to not like that it stays open you can automatically close it via the `CompleteDone` autocmd event. Do so by adding the following to your `vimrc` file.

```
augroup completion_preview_close
  autocmd!
  autocmd CompleteDone * if !&previewwindow && &completeopt =~ 'preview' | silent! pclose | endif
augroup END
```

For more help see:

```
:h 'completeopt'
:h preview-window
:h :pclose
:h CompleteDone
```